# Dart explicit operators like C#?

Tags: dart

In C# you can do an explicit operator as a static function in a class so that if you know how to convert from one type to another that normally wouldn't work you can have your class do it and it just works anywhere it expects the other type you can just put in the first type.

Does Dart have this?

Comment: Dart doesn't have implicit cast operators; conversions between unrelated types must always be explicitly done via a method call.

Comment: @jamesdlin Not only through a method call, but also through a call to any function. It's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the same but you can implement it if you need it.
Errors can only be detected at runtime.

```
void main() {
  final str1 = '123';
  final int i = str1.castTo();
  print(i);
  final str2 = 'true';
  final bool b = str2.castTo();
  print(b);
}

extension Cast on String {
  T castTo<T>() {
    switch (T) {
      case int:
        return int.parse(this) as T;
      case bool:
        switch (this) {
          case 'false':
            return false as T;
          case 'true':
            return true as T;
        }
    }

    throw StateError('Unable to convert to type: $T');
  }
}
```

Output:

```
123
true
```

Comment: Ok, not really the same thing. In C# you can just set the equality and it works, which is super nice for brevity.  Thanks though!